# INNER JOIN not working for me

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I'm currently working on a database for my Magic: The Gathering Playgroup which keeps track of decks and more specific which decks win against how many others and so on.

The table "Wins" looks like the following:

- PNr (Playernumber which is primary key in the table players)
- DNr (Decknumber which is primary key in the table decks)
- Date (combined primary key with MNr)
- MNr (Matchnumber of the day)
- Pl (Amount of Players in the game)
- Loc (Location)
- Code (containing of all the playing players Shortcuts, e.g. AMT for the Players Alex, Martin and Tobias, see below)

The table Players is pretty easy:

- PNr
- Pname (Playersname)
- SC (Players Shortcut)

Now I wanted to make a Query that provides a table of Expected Winrate (which is 1/4 in a 4 Player game, 1/5 in a 5 player game etc.) and the actual amount of Wins for each player (and later on Expected and actual Winrate but I think I can workthat out on my own once I got this baby to work).
So far I've come up with smth like this:

```
SELECT a.'Player',a.'ExpectedWinrate',b.'Wins'
FROM(
SELECT  
ROUND(((SUM(1/Pl))/Count(*))*100, 1) as 'ExpectedWinrate', 
Players.Pname as 'Player' 
FROM 
Wins, Players 
WHERE Code LIKE CONCAT('%', Players.SC, '%') 
GROUP BY Players.Pname) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
Count(*) as 'Wins', 
Players.Pname as 'Players' 
FROM Players, Wins 
WHERE Players.PNr = Wins.PNr 
GROUP BY Players.Pname 
ORDER BY Count(*) desc) b ON 'Players' = 'Player';
```

The problem that I've run into is that I need the Count(*) for two different things in one query so I had to make two independent ones and join them, but I don't know how to "name" them (in this case I tried with "a" and "b") in order to use expressions like **a.**'Player', **a.**'ExpectedWinrate', etc.

Can anyone help a MYSQL newb?^^

greetzSP

EDIT: added expample tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Players
(
 PNr int primary key, 
 Pname varchar(20), 
 SC varchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO Players
(PNr, Pname, SC)
VALUES
(1, 'Tobias', 'T'),
(2, 'Alex', 'A'),
(3, 'Martin', 'M'),
(4, 'Maria', 'R');

CREATE TABLE Wins
    (
     PNr int,
     DNr int,
     Pl int,
     Code varchar(10)
    );

INSERT INTO Wins
 (PNr, DNr, Pl, Code)
VALUES
(1, 13, 3, 'ATM'),
(4, 1, 4, 'RTMA'),
(3, 20, 3, 'RTM');
```

Wins: (leaving out columns that don't matter in this query)

```
| PNR | DNR | PL | CODE |
|-----|-----|----|------|
|   1 |  13 |  3 |  ATM |
|   4 |   1 |  4 | RTMA |
|   3 |  20 |  3 |  RTM |
```

Players:

```
| PNR |  PNAME | SC |
|-----|--------|----|
|   1 | Tobias |  T |
|   2 |   Alex |  A |
|   3 | Martin |  M |
|   4 |  Maria |  R |
```

Comment: Is not clear how data are stored on tables, can you post some data and examples on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: edited requested table data etc in

Comment: ` but I don't know how to "name" them` try `FROM 
Wins b, Players a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Player ,a.ExpectedWinrate ,b.Wins
FROM(
    SELECT  
            ROUND(((SUM(1/w.Pl))/Count(*))*100, 1) as 'ExpectedWinrate'
            ,p.Pname as 'Player' 
    FROM Wins w inner join Players p
    on w.Code LIKE CONCAT('%', p.SC, '%') 
    GROUP BY p.Pname
) a
inner join
(
    SELECT 
            Count(*) as 'Wins'
            ,p.Pname as 'Players' 
    FROM Players p inner join Wins w
    on p.PNr = w.PNr 
    GROUP BY p.Pname 
    --ORDER BY Count(*) desc
) b
ON a.Player = b.Players
```

I have tested it on SQL Server, try on MySQL

Comment: thanks, lookslike the only thing i f***ed up was that I used '-s in a.ExpectedWinrate etc...